# How do I get that a WebSphere application has been installed in Jython?

Tags: websphere, jython, ear, wsadmin

When I deploy an `.ear` application in WebSphere I have a problem in installing the shared libraries. I use a workaround to solve my issue like that

```
  [... code to install the application]
  && sleep 60 
  && /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin/wsadmin.sh -lang jython -c \
    "AdminApp.edit('appname', ['-MapSharedLibForMod', [['.*','.*', 'ibm']]])"
```

because I need to be sure that the `.ear` file has been installed before calling `AdminApp.edit`

How can I get rid of the `sleep` command? Is there a way to get a signal that the app has been installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my deploy script (bash) I call:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

$DM_WAS_HOME/wsadmin.sh -f $SCRIPTS_HOME/application_deploy.jacl $WORKING_DIRECTORY/appServer/$EAR_NAME $dmserver

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then 
    $DM_WAS_HOME/wsadmin.sh -lang jython -f $SCRIPTS_HOME/link_shared_lib.jython
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
         echo "ERROR: could not link libraries."
         exit 2
    fi
else
    echo "ERROR: installation failed, fix it"
    exit 1
fi
```

Anything goes wrong in the wsadmin.sh installation and the exit status is not 0.  This way if your install takes more time for some reason, it will not be an issue, since only when the first task is done will you move on.

The application installation jacl sets a bunch of variables and calls:

```tcl
$AdminApp update $appname app $updateopts
$adminConfig save
foreach nodeName $SyncNode {
    puts "Syncing $nodeName"
    $AdminControl invoke $nodeName sync
}
```

So anything does not work correctly in there, the exit status is != 0.
*Yes I know I have to rewrite my jacl into jython (still on WAS 7 for this application).*